# Rails 6 how to check if sidekiq job is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In my Rails 6 API only app I've got `FetchAllProductsWorker` background job which takes around 1h30m.

```
module Imports
  class FetchAllProductsWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options queue: 'imports_fetch_all'

    def perform
      # do some things
    end
  end
end
```

During this time the frontend app sends requests to the endpoint on BE which checks if the job is still running. I need to send `true/false` of that process. According to the docs there is a scan method - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#scan but none of these works for me even when worker is up and running:

```
# endpoint method to check sidekiq status
def status
  ss = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new

  render json: ss.scan('FetchAllProductsWorker') { |job| job.present? }
end
```

The console shows me:

```
> ss.scan("\"class\":\"FetchAllProductsWorker\"") {|job| job }
=> nil
> ss.scan("FetchAllProductsWorker") { |job| job }
=> nil
```

How to check if particular sidekiq process is not finished?

Comment: Your job could set a key in redis (with TTL) when it starts and delete it when it exits. Your frontend could then check existence of this key.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no idea what you're talking about. Any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will be useful for someone. Sidekiq provides programmatic access to the current active worker using `Sidekiq::Workers` https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#workers

So based on that we could do something like:

```
active_workers = Sidekiq::Workers.new.map do |_process_id, _thread_id, work|
  work
end

active_workers.select do |worker|
  worker['queue'] == 'imports_fetch_all'
end.present?
```